# I am trying to log in discord but i am getting an error code

Tags: python, python-requests, discord

i am trying to login in discord with python requests but i get error code 400. I know i could use the discord.py library or some other but i am trying to do it in requests for now.
This is the code i use:

```
def login():
    loginpayload = { "login": EMAIL, "password": PASSWORD, "undelete": "false"}
    headers = { "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_0_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36"}
    r = s.post("https://discord.com/api/v8/auth/login", loginpayload, headers)
    print(r.url)
    print(r.status_code)

login()
```

I am getting error code 400, heres my console output:

```
https://discord.com/api/v8/auth/login
400
```

Comment: You should look at the response content. Also note that discord has a perfectly good API that is much easier than trying to use the human interface from a program.

Comment: {'code': 50035, 'errors': {'_errors': [{'code': 'CONTENT_TYPE_INVALID', 'message': 'Expected "Content-Type" header to be one of {\'application/json\'}.'}]}, 'message': 'Invalid Form Body'}

Comment: Please edit your answer with the error

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're sending an invalid form body.

Your payload must be like this instead:

`loginpayload = { "login": EMAIL, "password": PASSWORD, "undelete": "false", "captcha_key": "null", "login_source": "null", "gift_code_sku_id": "null"}`

This will return the captcha page which you will have to solve and send it back by replacing the value of `captcha_key`.